# Link between Hadamard's inequality for positive-definite matrices and general Hadamard's inequality

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant

I've found two versions of Hadamard's inequality :

(1) If $P$ is a $n\times n$ positive-semidefinite matrix, then :
 $$\det(P)\le\prod_{i=1}^n p_{ii} .$$
(2) For any $M$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, then :
$$|\det(M)|\le\prod_{i=1}^n ||m_i || =\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n |a_{ij}|^2\right)^{1/2}.$$
It's easy to prove that $(2)\Rightarrow (1)$, but do we have $(1)\Rightarrow (2)$ ?

Comment: Yes it does. Let $M$ be any matrix. Then $MM^t$ is a positive semi-definite matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using comment of @mouthetics,

From (1) we know that  $\sqrt{\det(MM^T)}\le\prod_{i=1}^n\{MM^T\}_{ii}^{1/2}=\prod_{i=1}^n \left(\sum_{j=1}^n |m_{ij}|^2\right)^{1/2}=\prod_{i=1}^n ||m_i ||$

Since $\det(MM^T)=\det(M)\det(M^T)=\det(M)^2$

we have $|\det(M)|=\sqrt{\det(MM^T)}\le\prod_{i=1}^n ||m_i ||$.